# CakePHP 3 - set different layout from plugin controller

Tags: cakephp, layout, plugins, controller, cakephp-3.0

How to set different layout from an Action of a plugin controller. The layout files are in the general Template/Layout directory of the app.

I tried:

`$this->viewBuilder()->layout('login_layout');`

and it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try with below code

```
$this->ViewBuilder()->layoutPath("");
$this->viewBuilder()->layout('login_layout');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I solved it by my self. It was my fault: I was overriding  

$this->viewBuilder()->layout('login_layout');  inside action in UsersController  with:

$this->viewBuilder()->layout('app_layout');
inside beforeRender on AppController